# How to make a layout dependent on the domain, and not on the module?

Tags: zend-framework2

I have an application in which there are several sub-domains. I redirect to modules based on domains. Each module have a different layout. Is based on evandotpro/edp-module-layouts :

```
public function onBootstrap($e)
{
     $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager()->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController', 'dispatch', function($e) {
     ... 
     ...
```

In addition i have authentication module - it is global.

```
client.app.com/auth/login
handheld.app.com/auth/login
```

are associated with the same module

However, I would keep the layout of the module associated with the domain.

Of course I have an idea for a couple of hacks that solve this problem, but I'm interested in whether there is any "clean" solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dirty hack that i used.:

- I have module Terminal with own layout. And conected with own
  domain  ( route type Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Hostname )

  - for example http://termina.example.com/
- and I have module Auth that add authorization in whole
  application and redirect to login page

  - so when not authorized uset try to acces to terminal module is redirect to:
  - http://terminal.example.com/login (route connected with Auth module)

So to force Terminal layout in that situation I add Terminal Module.php:

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $e)
{
    $e->getApplication()->getEventManager()->getSharedManager()->attach('Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController', 'dispatch', function($e) {
        $controller      = $e->getTarget();
        $controllerClass = get_class($controller);
        $moduleNamespace = substr($controllerClass, 0, strpos($controllerClass, '\\'));

        if ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] == 
                $e->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('config')['router']['routes']['terminal']['options']['route']
                && $moduleNamespace=='Auth') { 
            $controller->layout('layout/terminal');
        }
    }, 1);
}
```

and, as always, sorry for my english...